# Select 3rd highest values from the table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to select 3rd highest values from the table in SQL Server (or any value from the table)

Comment: Are you asking something?

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for the solution, but then tried to figure out it myself.
The solution posted by you, is well-written, just curious to know if that is optimized or can be further optimized, from memory point of view, as it adds a new column in the in-memory temp table( I think it would be temporary) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  TOP 1 with TIES prod.product_name, 
    prod.list_price FROM(
                    SELECT
                        product_name , 
                        list_price 
                    FROM
                        production.products
                    ORDER BY 
                        list_price DESC
                        Offset 2 ROWS
                        **Fetch First 4 Rows Only**
                    )  as prod
    Order BY list_price  desc
```

This query fetches all the 3rd highest valued products from the table( if there are many with the same price/value).
Here you can replace/update Offset value to fetch 2nd, 3rd,4th and so on, values from the table. Also, you can add the Fetch First ( Row Count) Rows Only to limit the required positional value.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, if you want the third highest *distinct* value, you would use:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*, dense_rank() over (order by listprice desc) as seqnum
      from products p
     ) p
where seqnum = 3;
```

If you just wanted the row that is third when ordered by price:

```
select p.*
from products p
order b listprice desc
offset 2 fetch first 1 row only;
```

Comment: @SiddharthRawat . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?